# PHPSpreadsheet add borders to ODS file

Tags: php, spreadsheet, phpspreadsheet, ods, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to add borders to my ODS file but it doesn't seem to work.

Tried to save the file with the Xlsx writer and it works perfectly.

Here's the code :

```
 $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $activeWorksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $activeWorksheet->getStyle('A1:E28')->applyFromArray([
            'borders' => [
                'allBorders' => [
                'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THIN,
                    'color' => [
                        Color::COLOR_BLACK
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ods writer does not seem to be capable of doing that. You need to write as xlsx file instead which can be opened in Open Office as well.

```
$writer = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('test.xlsx');
```